# OWL ontology hierarchy (with complex classes) using Jena

Tags: jena, owl, ontology, protege, owl-api

I am trying to use Jena API to create a hierarchy of OWL ontology, which is similar to the one created by Protege. I have tried two methods to get subclasses of owl:Thing and then recurs for next levels.:

1. Using the **listSubClasses(true)**
2. Using the **listHierarchyRootClasses()**

They both have worked for the OWL classes having rdfs:subClassOf as owl:Thing. However, for OWL complex classes (owl:unionOf, owl:intersectionOf, and owl:complementOf), the first method has not listed anything. While the result of the second method has not been as correct as Protege. It often includes more subclasses of owl:Thing than Protege does.

Someone said that is the limitation of Jena API. Is it true? Should I switch to using OWL API instead of Jena? I would like to have your advice.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is a reasoner. You cannot have complete results without using a reasoner to infer subclass relationships. this is true for both Jena and OWL API.

Comment: Thank you, Igazio! I have tried with built-in reasoner of Jena. The result is better. But it is different from the result of Protege. Someone said that Protege uses a lightweight reasoner to show the hierarchy of ontology (in asserted mode). My question is: which reasoner I should use to have a hierarchy same as the one of Protege?

Comment: Protégé does not use a reasoner for the display in asserted mode, it uses a few hardcoded rules. The only way to replicate is to find and copy that code...

Comment: Yes, or maybe I must use Protege-OWL API as some plugins of Protege do. Once again, thank you!